# WinSCP .NET assembly fails with "The winscp.exe executable was not found" in Session.Open in C# Azure function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

First I generated a simple console application to see if the generated by WinSCP works fine - and this was the case

Now I try to write an Azure function using WinSCP - in the same way - the same parameters - and I get an exception on `Session.Open` (SessionLocalException):

> [Error] Executed 'WriteFile' (Failed, Id=68e2ef30-c2fb-4f5e-8444-93634a2728bb, Duration=256ms)
> The winscp.exe executable was not found at location of the assembly WinSCPnet (D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin), nor the entry assembly Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost (D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\3.2.0\32bit), nor in an installation path. You may use Session.ExecutablePath property to explicitly set path to winscp.exe.

The `winscp.exe` file is not in `D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin` but in `D:\home\site\wwwroot`. And as I'm publishing via Visual studio it is read only so I cannot just copy the file on the right location.

How can update my zip deployment so that the file gets in the right place?

My code :

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> WriteFile(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
{
    SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
    {
        Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
        HostName = "xxx",
        UserName = "xxx",
        Password = "xxx",
        SshHostKeyFingerprint = "xxx",
    };
    using (Session session = new Session())
    {
        try
        {
            session.Open(sessionOptions);
        }
        catch (SessionLocalException)
        {
            content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { success = false, exception = "SessionLocalException", condition = "Error communicating with winscp.com. See the exception documentation for details." });
            return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"{content}");
        }
```

Exception documentation for details does not help very much
Could anybody help me?

---

In a first time I wrote directly in Azure portal some functions to process SFTP related activities - I was new to Azure Functions but I found a way to get it handled

Now I try to write these functions in Visual Studio 2019 to publish to Azure functions

The problem is that in the C# code when I try to open a session it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exact problem is documented in [WinSCP guide to transfers in Microsoft Azure Function](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_microsoft_azure_function_sftp):

> The only problem you will face is, that for some reason, when publishing the project to an Azure storage, `winscp.exe` dependency is stored to the root folder of the function, instead of the `bin` subfolder along with other binaries (particularly the `WinSCPnet.dll`).
>
> To overcome that, you need to use [`Session.ExecutablePath`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session#executablepath) to point to the actual location of `winscp.exe`. You can use `ExecutionContext.FunctionAppDirectory` to refer to the root folder of the function. To get an instance of the [`ExecutionContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#executioncontext), add new parameter to the signature of your entry method (usually `Run`).
>
> ```cs
> [FunctionName("Function1")]
> public static void Run(
>     [TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
> {
>     // ...
>     session.ExecutablePath = Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "winscp.exe");
> }
> ```

(for full code, see the guide)

---

After all, the exception message suggests the same:

> You may use Session.ExecutablePath property to explicitly set path to winscp.exe.